# AST2150 Console Redirection (KVM over IP)

Tags: linux, hardware, ipmi, keyboard-video-mouse

I am using AST2150 Base Board Management Controller which supports KVM over IP. It's connected to the network. Everything is good except the Console Redirection. The console redirection comes up as a blank screen. Is there anything special that needs to be done for Console Redirection to work. The machine with BMC has Linux running in non GUI mode. I searched around but couldn't find anything specific to this problem.

Comment: Is the Linux console blanked out? Tap a key...

Comment: Already tried that many times. Doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The box was using external VGA card. Removed the card and enabled the AST2150 VGA on the board. It works now. It didn't work when external VGA card was in place even when AST2150 VGA was enabled.